# Combine two column values into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns in my SQL table where the phone numbers are stored.
I have displayed both the numbers separated by a ",".
If I concatenate both the data with "," for displaying, the problem I am facing is - when the first column is blank I am getting the output as ",xxxxxxxxxx" and when the second column is blank I am getting the output as "xxxxxxxxx,".
I am getting the perfect output only when both the columns contain data like "xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx".

How can I remove the extra "," when the data for either of the columns are missing?

Comment: what's your PHP code at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```
$ret = implode(',', array_filter(array($value1, $value2)));
```

Comment: I think this will still do what OP produce.

Comment: @SandeepBajoria Added the `array_filter` to filter the empty value, try again.

Answer (score 1):

**WHY checking that using PHP when it could be addressed inside MySQL Query??**

You can do that right into the query while pulling data using [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS( ',', NULL , 'col2' ) ;
```

**OUTPUT:** col2

However, this will only work if the empty field is set as `NULL`. If you empty field isn't NULL, you can further put `IF` condition to set that parameter as `NULL` if field is empty e.g.

```
 SELECT CONCAT_WS( ',', IF(col1 = '', NULL, col1) , 'col2' ) ;
```